# Trouble get value from another page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

This is the function i am using for get value from another page this function is showing result in html div but i want to get result in text box.

```
function refresh_div()
{
   jQuery.ajax({
       url:'query.php',
       type:'POST',
       success:function(results) 
       {     
           jQuery(".r1").html(results);      
       }
   });
}
```

Comment: What/Which textbox..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you have a textbox with the class `r1`.
Use `val` instead of `html` for `<form>` elements such `<input>`, `<textarea>` `<select>`, `<progressbar>` etc.

Example of usage:

```
jQuery(".r1").val(results);
```

Comment: @user2897328n no problem, just next time please clarify your issue in hand, it was very difficult to understand your problem.